# How do I avoid my scipy interpolated spline from adding extraneous zeros?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to fit a spline to my array: dej

when I use interpolate.splrep I'm getting output that is longer, and the last x-coordinate is repeated 4 times, and their y value is 0, while the first x value is repeated 4 times, each overwriting one other data point and extending the array by 2.  My whole array is 4 points longer.

```
    In [12]: len(dej[:,0])
    Out[12]: 140

    In [13]: len(dej[:,1])
    Out[13]: 140

    In [14]: moo = interpolate.splrep(dej[:,0],dej[:,1])

    In [15]: len(moo)
    Out[15]: 3

    In [16]: len(moo[0])
    Out[16]: 144

    In [17]: len(moo[1])
    Out[17]: 144
```

This causes an offset in the data so the fitted spline doesn't overlay on the data. This is probably a property of smoothing, but is there a way to turn it off?

[image of offset fit and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D06Iw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use `splrep(x, y, s=0)` to force interpolation (the `s` parameter controls the level of smoothing)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it seems to make little difference.